# Apollo directory not generated

Tags: android, gradle, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am having difficulty in the initial implementation.
My problem is that the following build could not generate the apollo directory.

With this gradle (app level)

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'kotlin-android'
  id 'kotlin-kapt'
  id 'com.apollographql.apollo'
}

android {
  compileSdk 31

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
  }

}

dependencies {

  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


  // The core runtime dependencies
  implementation"com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:2.5.9"
  // Coroutines extensions for easier asynchronicity handling
  implementation"com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-coroutines-support:2.5.9"

}

apollo {
  generateKotlinModels.set(true)
}
```

And this gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30"
    classpath "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:2.5.9"

  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Using this schema.graphql

```
schema {
    query: Query
}

type Continent {
    code: ID!
    countries: [Country!]!
    name: String!
}

type Country {
    capital: String
    code: ID!
    continent: Continent!
    currency: String
    emoji: String!
    emojiU: String!
    languages: [Language!]!
    name: String!
    native: String!
    phone: String!
    states: [State!]!
}

type Language {
    code: ID!
    name: String
    native: String
    rtl: Boolean!
}

type Query {
    continent(code: ID!): Continent
    continents(filter: ContinentFilterInput): [Continent!]!
    countries(filter: CountryFilterInput): [Country!]!
    country(code: ID!): Country
    language(code: ID!): Language
    languages(filter: LanguageFilterInput): [Language!]!
}

type State {
    code: String
    country: Country!
    name: String!
}

enum CacheControlScope {
    PRIVATE
    PUBLIC
}

input ContinentFilterInput {
    code: StringQueryOperatorInput
}

input CountryFilterInput {
    code: StringQueryOperatorInput
    continent: StringQueryOperatorInput
    currency: StringQueryOperatorInput
}

input LanguageFilterInput {
    code: StringQueryOperatorInput
}

input StringQueryOperatorInput {
    eq: String
    glob: String
    in: [String]
    ne: String
    nin: [String]
    regex: String
}


"The `Upload` scalar type represents a file upload."
scalar Upload
```

generated by this configuration

```
{
  "name": "Untitled GraphQL Schema",
  "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {
      "Default GraphQL Endpoint": {
        "url": "https://countries.trevorblades.com/",
        "headers": {
          "user-agent": "JS GraphQL"
        },
        "introspect": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't generate the Apollo folder

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you put the code you posted as `schema.graphql` ?

You can found the following example in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/stefanosansone/apollo-countries).
*(It's a sample application I made using [trevorblades countries API](https://countries.trevorblades.com/) and [Apollo GraphQL](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/) 2.5.9, so i think it fits your needs perfectly)*

---

First of all you need to [download the server's schema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/tutorial/02-add-the-graphql-schema/) with the following command *(replace the path with your app's name and package)*

```sh
mkdir -p app/src/main/graphql/com/example/rocketreserver/
./gradlew :app:downloadApolloSchema --endpoint='https://countries.trevorblades.com/' --schema='app/src/main/graphql/com/example/rocketreserver/schema.json'
```

This will generate the `schema.json` in the specified path, after which you can [write all the queries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/tutorial/03-write-your-first-query/) you need creating files like `countries.graphql` or `continents.graphql`.
Make sure you put them in the same folder as `schema.json`.

[image]

In my example you can find a query for the list of countries and one for the country detail.

`CountryList.graphql`

```
query CountriesList {
  countries {
    code
    name
    continent{
      code
      name
    }
    languages{
      code
      name
    }
    emoji
  }
}
```

`CountryDetail.graphql`

```
query CountryDetail($code:ID!) {
  country(code: $code) {
    code
    name
    phone
    continent{
      code
      name
    }
    capital
    currency
    languages{
      code
      name
    }
    emoji
  }
}
```

At this point you just need to build the project to [generate](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/tutorial/03-write-your-first-query/#generate-the-model) the apollo directory and the models you defined.

[image]